# .index() function in python not working

Tags: python, string

I'm completing a school assignment in python where a user must enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy and i have to split each part (dd, mm, yyyy) and store them in a list.

```
date = input("Enter a date in the following format 'dd/mm/yyyy: "); 
date = date+'/'

    def split(date):
        dates = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(date):
            x = date.index('/', i)
            dates.append(date[i:x])
            i = x
        return dates
```

This is the code i used. I'm searching for the character '/' in my string 'date' and then extracting a substring from date which I am appending to the list dates.

Apparently my .index() function isnt working as I hoped it would. Is it because I cant pass a variable as an argument for the index function? Or is there some other problem.

I know the index() function is the problem because when I print the value of x just after the iteration, the value of x doesn't get updated.

This is the output i get after troubleshooting 
    i=0 x=2 dates = ['12'] 
    i=2 x=2 dates = ['12','']

and it continues into an infinite loop

Any help on this matter would be appreciated :')

Comment: Have you heard of the ``time`` and ``datetime`` modules in the Python standard library?

Comment: Somehow, I don't think these were what the OP's tutor is after. Of course this is trivial when you've learnt some string methods, but is it really that long since you learnt a language starting with `print 'hello World'`?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your code keeps finding the same instance each time.

```
i = x + 1
```

Don't forget to handle the part where there are no more to find.

Comment: I've added the statement i=x which should ideally update the value of i after each iteration.

Comment: Read the first sentence of my answer again.

Comment: ohh yeahhh, of course, i got it now, thank you so much

Comment: I've done this before in java using a for loop, and i forgot that i used to have a update statement with 'i++' in the loop. Since the syntax for loops in java and python are different, i forgot to incorporate that part. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I should probably start using Jython from now on I guess :')

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

def date_split(date_input):
    try:
        date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_input, "%d/%m/%Y") # This line with validate input
    except ValueError:
        print "Please verify input format and range : ", date_input
        return
    else:
        return [date_obj.day, date_obj.month, date_obj.year]

date = raw_input("Enter a date in the following format dd/mm/yyyy: ")
print date_split(str(date))
```